# Drf: Getting related posts by ManyToMany category and a tags field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get all related posts by getting the id of the current post and filtering through the DB to find posts that are either in a similar category or have similar tags.

**this is the model for the posts:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ....
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        "users.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    tags = TaggableManager()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Category')
    ....
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=blog_STATUS, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**this is the views.py file:**

```
class RelatedPostsListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostsSerializer
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.filter(
        status=1)[:5]
    model = BlogPost

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(RelatedPostsListAPIView,
                    self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    pk = self.kwargs['pk']
    main_post = BlogPost.objects.get(pk=pk)

    related_posts = main_post.filter(
        Q(categories__in=main_post.categories.all()) |
        Q(tags__in=main_post.tags.all())).exclude(pk=pk)[:5]

    context['related_posts'] = related_posts
    return context
```

**this is the serializer**

```
    class CategoriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'slug']


class PostsSerializer(TaggitSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categories = CategoriesSerializer(many=True)
    author = UserSerializer()
    tags = TagListSerializerField()
    cover = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')

    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = [
            "id",
            "title",
            "slug",
            "author",
            "description",
            "content",
            "tags",
            "categories",
            "keywords",
            "cover",
            "created_on",
            "updated_on",
            "status",
        ]

    def get_image_url(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        return request.build_absolute_uri(obj.cover.url)
```

**url pattern:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('all/', PostsListAPIView.as_view(), name="all_posts"),
    path('recent/', RecentPostsListAPIView.as_view(), name="recent_posts"),
    path('related/<int:pk>/', RelatedPostsListAPIView.as_view(), name="related_posts")
]
```

with this code I get a `RelatedPostsListAPIView.get() got multiple values for argument 'pk'` error, I don't think I am actually getting the object with the id, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: might be an error with your request, can we see the URL from the request and the code from PostsSerializer?

Comment: also you might want to wrap your queryset in `get_queryset`
`def get_queryset(self): return BlogPost.objects.filter(status=1)[:5]`, because the [:5] will render the queryset itself

Comment: i ave edited in the url pattern and serializer

Comment: I had a ``get_queryset`` method but ``get_queryset`` doesn't accept anything except ``self`` right?

Comment: yes, that is correct, but you don't need anything else to be passed in, `queryset` and `get_queryset` work in the base class as defined here: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/71e6c30034a1dd35a39ca74f86c371713e762c79/rest_framework/generics.py#L48

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to capture `request` in `get()`, so change:

```py
class RelatedPostsListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get(self, pk):
        # ...
```

to:

```py
class RelatedPostsListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        #         ^^^ Add this
```

Comment: didn't solve the issue but thanks.

Comment: Is it still the same error?

Comment: yes it says ``GenericAPIView.get_object() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given``

Comment: That's a different error from the original question so it means that was fixed. We could help if you are able to put all the relevant code here. So far that error seems to be because `get_object` does not accept any arguments but you are passing `pk`

Comment: okay I have changed the get method with get_context_data I have added the code the view renders the posts but I don't think it is working since it is not omitting the post that the query was filtered against.